# Load balancing between two routers

Tags: router

I have the following network:

[image]

On LAN A, several hosts (only three represented on the picture, but you can assume it's like 100) are connected with two Linux routers to LAN B. My goal is to use both R1 and R2 to route traffic to LAN B. That mean there is a load balancing system sending approximately half the data through one router, and the other half through the second one. There is two options:

- 50% of my hosts use R1, the other half R2 (like in the figure above). This can be done by manually setting the gateway on each host, but as it's manual operations, that is not an optimal solution. The other solution is to have a DHCP that can give different gateway, but I'm not sure it is possible.
- Every hosts split their data between R1 and R2.

The hosts are PC that need to send data to LAN B or Internet. They do not send data to each other (and if so, that's only layer 2 communications inside LAN A). R3 is the main enterprise output router. It has enough bandwidth to handle the traffic alone, while R1 and R2 are Linux based router that are not good enough. I know I could just use a better router instead, but this is done in a project where the goal is to provide a load balancing routing function.

Cisco has a protocol called GLBP to achieve that, which is, of course, not available for other router brand. So, how can I configure a load balancing system ?

Comment: Are there servers in the network or are pc's communicating to eachother in the network, or is all traffic eventually directed to the internet?

Comment: This is very confusing. (1) If Host A and Host B can’t talk to each other directly (without going through a router), they aren’t on the same LAN.  (2) 2/3 is 66⅔%; 1/3 is 33⅓%.  (3) If you are using Linux machines as routers, that’s probably worth mentioning as a key fact, and not hiding as an aside in the last paragraph.  (4) What is your objective?  Why are you using three routers? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott Updated.